# ¿Como puedo convertir este código asp a código para aplicación Windows Form en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, archivo

tengo el código que se muestra en la imagen que es para una aplicación web y lo utilizo para subir cualquier tipo de archivos y me muestra el nombre del archivo pero ahora quiero hacer lo mismo pero para una aplicación Windows Form en c# [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no estaria entendiendo.. en una aplicacion de escritorio no vas a subir un archivo. Podes explicar un poco mejor la idea?

Comment: Hola.. lo que pasa que el código que subí es para un ejemplo web pero ahora quiero subir cualquier tipo de archivos para una aplicación de escritorio pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo..

Comment: a que te referis con subir? subir adonde? si estas en el escritorio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso del `FileUpload`, es un control diseñado para poder interactuar con el `Browser` y el `Servidor` y poder almacenar un archivo en una ubicación X, del lado del `Servidor`. Ahora bien, analógicamente con una aplicación de escritorio, lo que tienes que hacer es copiar el archivo de la ubicación original, a donde quieras almacenarlo.

Para buscar el archivo que deseas mover, puedes usar un `OpenFileDialog` (información [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx), video explicando su implementación [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pz4HcKExtBc))

Para hacerlo lo más parecido al control en la parte Web, puedes usar un `TextBox`, y usar el evento `onClick`, para abrir en ese momento el buscador de archivos y un Button, para mover el archivo, de la siguiente manera:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog archivo = new OpenFileDialog();
   archivo.Title = "Archivos a mover";
   if (archivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      textBox1.Text = archivo.FileName;
      //le pones la propiedad ReadOnly en true, para que no puedan cambiar 
      //la ruta que devuelve el control OpenFileDialog.
   }
}
```

Una vez con la ruta, con un botón mueves el archivo y listo

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
   string destino = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\miCarpetaDestino", nombreArchivo);
   System.IO.File.Copy(textBox1.Text, destino, true);
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho tu respuesta, la verdad soy nueva en esto y aun no entiendo algunas cosas..

Comment: Un placer haberte ayudado